# ¿Que impacto tiene en el uso de recursos al momento de declarar e Instanciar de una forma determinada en Java?

Tags: java, rendimiento, buenas-prácticas

Muy buenas, me gustaría saber la diferencia que existe específicamente en el ámbito del uso de recursos en las siguientes lineas de código:

```
//Opción 1
Object variable;
variable = new Object(); 

//Opción 2
Object variable2 = new Object();
```

Siendo mas concreto, lo que realmente quiero saber es lo siguiente:
¿Cual de las dos opciones gasta mas recursos en la maquina?

Comment: Bueno. Ya tienes claro que declarar e instanciar son cosas diferentes y tienen efectos diferentes. Lo que no está claro en tu pregunta es a qué te refieres con eficiente. ¿Dónde buscas ser eficiente?

Comment: @Alfabravo tienes razón, al final puse una pregunta mas especifica.

Comment: Al final de cada opción, usan la misma cantidad de memoria y, salvo que la opción 1 se implemente de forma esotérica, el class va a ser igual. La declaración avisa con qué vas a trabajar, la instanciación es la que hace algo en el heap (o en el stack según sea el caso). Como la declaración no hace nada en memoria, es por eso que es mala práctica andar con atributos declarados sin instanciar por defecto (receta para el NPE)